# SSAS Adding description attribute causes deployment error

Tags: deployment, ssas, cube

I am building my first multidimensional data cube, so I am just starting the learning curve.

I can easily create the data sources, views, cubes and dimensions, I can also deploy the solution to localhost where I have an analysis services instance installed.

The problems start when I try to add attributes to my dimensions. Particular a Part dimension that features an attribute called Purchase_Part_Description

If I remove this attribute, the cube deploys without errors, if I leave in this attribute then I get the following error

```
Warning     Errors in the OLAP storage engine: The attribute key cannot be found when processing: Table: 'dbo_Dim_Purchase_Part', Column: 'Purchase_Part_Description', Value: 'IC, AMPLIFIER, GAAS PHEMT'. The attribute is 'Purchase Part Description'.            0
```

On my database I do have 4 rows of part numbers named 'IC, AMPLIFIER, GAAS PHEMT' But they all have different key values, that are used to link the part to my fact table.

Any idea where to start troubleshooting?

every single setting in the cube has been left untouched

Answer (score 0):

You probably have values in the foreign key column of the fact table that refers to that dimension, which do not exist as keys in the dimension. You should have some sort of unknown -member in the dimension, and set the surrogate key for that member for all the rows that does not have a real relation from the fact table.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I can fiddle with keycolumns and namecolumn in order for this error to go away.